Office Interop: Cancellation
Let's say I want to convert a PowerPoint file to a PDF file using Office Interop:
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

Application app = null;
try
{
    app = new Application();

    Presentation doc = app.Presentations.Open("Document.pptx", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    doc.SaveAs("Document.pdf", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    doc.Close();
}
finally
{
    if (app != null)
        app.Quit();
    app = null;
}

How can I cancel that?
SaveAs may require an unreasonable amount of time to finish in case the document is sufficiently complex. So, the user may want to cancel.

It's a remote COM RPC call. Maybe try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/com/canceling-method-calls or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-rpccancelthread or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcasync/nf-rpcasync-rpcasynccancelcall I'm going to guess that MS Powerpoint doesn't support cancellation. Have you thought about using OpenXML instead?

@Charlieface I've tried ICancelMethodCalls.Cancel - it makes the doc.SaveAs call return with an exception "Call was canceled by the message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))". But then, the app.Quit call hangs. Probably, PowerPoint does still execute SaveAs, only the client does not listen any more for the result. POWERPNT.EXE is still present in TaskManager.

@Charlieface : RpcCancelThread: Returns RPC_S_OK, but same behavior.
